# Null app on iPhone

Tags: iphone

How do I get rid of "null" app on list when I got into manage usage?? Gives option to delete app but keeps coming back on list. Shows no data associated with IT

Comment: The springboard data can be cleared by "reset all data and settings" so it's not clear if you have something that's repeatedly corrupting the iOS or a one time failure you can clear up. Please edit this to indicate what build of iOS and what source the app you are installing is or ask a new question linking here if it helps you frame your situation.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 9, do the following:

1. Open Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage > Manage Storage
2. Select the null app
3. Press the button marked Delete App

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.. i can't find a lot about it on internet. I think its a bug or something. I also had a problem with my iphone. My phone was shutting down after 4 or more hours without using. Only way to turn it on was with a 'hard' reboot. The reboot was necessary for 2 or 3 times en then de phone was working ok for a couple of days. Maybe 'null' has something te do with that? My only solution for now was clean complete iphone with iTunes, put on latest version of iOS (9.0.1) en replace the back-up of most things. For now 'Null' is gone and i hope my shut down problem also.

(Klaas, Holland, iPhone 5s)